# Hash para una contraseña con PHP 5.3

Tags: php

Conozco el comando para hash en PHP 5.5. o +++ pero no lo he encontrado en PHP 5.3.

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: Revisa la documentacion oficial, http://php.net/manual/es/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, debes descargarte una librería para compatibilizar las funciones del `PHP5.5` en el `PHP5.3.*`, luego usa simplemente la sintaxis del php5.5 :)

Te dejo el enlace de la librería

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Ejemplo de creación de un password Hash:

```
 $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```